# Observable subscription not getting called

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

I have an Observable that I'm using to convert a promise into a subscription. This results in a collection that I need to iterate through to call an HTTP Service on each element. I'm using forkJoin to wait for all those calls to finish so that I can do something else, but unfortunately, my subscription is not being called. Do you see what I'm missing here?

```
Observable.fromPromise(this.users.getElements()).subscribe(results => {
  Observable.forkJoin(
    results.map(
      aUser => this.HttpService.submitUser(aUser).subscribe(
        results => {
          this.progress += 1;
        },
        err => {
          this.progress += 1;
          this.handleError(<any>err);
        })
    ).subscribe(
      //it never gets to either of these calls after all service calls complete
      data => {
        debugger;
        console.log(data);
        this.reset();
      },
      err => {
        debugger;
        console.log(err);
        this.reset();
      }
    ));
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing is you don't subscribe to each Observable passed to `forkJoin()`. The operator has to do it itself.

If you want to be notified when each Observable completes you can use `.do(undefined, undefined, () => {...})`.

```
let observables = [
  Observable.of(42).do(undefined, undefined, () => console.log('done')),
  Observable.of('a').delay(100).do(undefined, undefined, () => console.log('done')),
  Observable.of(true).do(undefined, undefined, () => console.log('done')),
];

Observable.forkJoin(observables)
  .subscribe(results => console.log(results));
```

This prints to console:

```
done
done
done
[ 42, 'a', true ]
```

Eventually there's also `.finally()` operator. However, it's not the same as using `.do()`.

EDIT:

When any of the source Observables fail the `forkJoin()` operator reemits the error (which means it also fails).
This means you need to catch errors in each source Observable separately (with `catch()` operator for example).

```
let observables = [
  Observable.throw(new Error())
    .catch(() => Observable.of('caught error 1'))
    .do(undefined, undefined, () => console.log('done 1')),

  Observable.of('a')
    .delay(100).catch(() => Observable.of('caught error 2'))
    .do(undefined, undefined, () => console.log('done 2')),

  Observable.of(true)
    .catch(() => Observable.of('caught error 3'))
    .do(undefined, undefined, () => console.log('done 3')),
];

Observable.forkJoin(observables)
  .subscribe(results => console.log(results));
```

Which prints:

```
done 1
done 3
done 2
[ 'caught error 1', 'a', true ]
```

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean but if one of those observables has an exception, the forkJoin is picking it up right away before the others are completed. I thought forkJoin was supposed to wait for all to complete but from the source it looks like it will mark it "finished" rather than go to the next one. In my example, I want each observable to handle the error gracefully and continue. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to subscribe in the map.

```
Observable.fromPromise(this.users.getElements()).subscribe(results => {
  Observable.forkJoin(
    results.map(
      aUser => this.HttpService.submitUser(aUser))
    ).subscribe(
      //it never gets to either of these calls after all service calls complete
      data => {
        debugger;
        console.log(data);
        this.reset();
      },
      err => {
        debugger;
        console.log(err);
        this.reset();
      }
    ));
});
```

Note that in the rxjs example here:

https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/forkjoin.md

they don't subscribe to the individual observables -- ForkJoin gets them all going, then waits for all of them to return (in your subscribe.)

EDIT:

The forkjoin source is here:

https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/src/core/linq/observable/forkjoin.js

and it doesn't look like it has hooks to find out when each finishes.  I think the best way to approach a UI bar would be to have each of the mapped observables subscribed to individually that all call a function to increment the UI counting bar variable and have some test for "completeness" that allows you to use the data.

Comment: Yeah, but then how will I increment my counter (for UI progress bar) as each one completes?  Basically I want to do something as each one completes and then something else when they all complete.

Comment: I just looked into the forkjoin source, and I don't think it exposes anything that allows you to hook in and see when each one comes in.  I think you would have to subscribe to each of those maps individually and call some sort of counting function for your UI progress bar.